# iOS MDM: Configure iOS device as supervised through MDM server

Tags: ios, mdm

I am done with MDM server implementation for iOS devices. I want to make my device as supervised through MDM server while enrollment. Is it possible to do through MDM server?
If yes,can someone give me idea how to do it?
If no, then are there other ways to do it and how?
Please if possible provide sample plist to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this? I am able to configure my iPhone as supervised using apple configurator. Is there any way to install a profile that will make device as supervised through MDM server?

Comment: As Nabosi mentioned, an MDM server can "supervise" a device by integrating with Device Enrollment Program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supervision can only be done at activation time.  There is no way to supervise once the device is out of the Setup Assistant you see when you first start the phone.  You'll need to erase the device and start over to supervise.

You need to do supervision either through Apple Configurator or through the Device Enrollment Program (DEP) if you're using MDM to managed the device.  You can read more information about DEP, the current regions where it's available, and the restrictions here: https://www.apple.com/education/it/dep/

Comment: Is this answer still true? or is there any way to do it?

Comment: @Saurabh This is still true and Apple is unlikely to change this in the future as they use this as a security measure to prevent installation of things like Global HTTP Proxy onto a normal user's phone.

Comment: @Nobosi
I am seeing OurPact application, they giving us Mac application to supervise device before to install profile. So I think there is a way to do supervise device, are you aware with that? I want to make a Mac application that will supervise iOS device.